# stats_standard_deviation in php 5.2.13

Tags: php

I am using PHP version 5.2.13 with Kohana framework v2.3.4 and I want to calculate the standard deviation.

I found a function in the PHP manual: [stats_standard_deviation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stats-standard-deviation.php)

The problem is that when I try I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function stats_standard_deviation() in /folder/test.php on line 1799
```

This is the code I am using:

```
 function std_dev ($attr, $test1,$test2,$test3,$test4,$test5,$test6) {
    $items[] = array();

    if (isset($test1) && $test1->$attr != 9 && $test1->$attr != 0) {
        $items[] = $test1->$attr;
    }
    if (isset($test2) && $test2->$attr != 9  && $test2->$attr != 0) {
        $items[] = $test2->$attr;
    }
    if (isset($test3) && $test3->$attr != 9 && $test3->$attr != 0) {
        $items[] = $test3->$attr;
    }
    if (isset($test4) && $test4->$attr != 9 && $test4->$attr != 0) {
        $items[] = $test4->$attr;
    }
    if (isset($test5) && $test5->$attr != 9 && $test5->$attr != 0) {
        $items[] = $test5->$attr;
    }
    if (isset($test6) && $test6->$attr != 9 && $test6->$attr != 0) {
        $items[] = $test6->$attr;
    }

    $standard_deviation = stats_standard_deviation($items);

    return round($standard_deviation,2);

}
```

All help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post your code where you are calling it?

Comment: Stupid question I know, but you're sure that the PECL package is available to your install/setup?

Comment: @LokiSinclair - That's not a stupid question, it's probably the case...

Comment: I updated the post with the code I am using

Comment: Check the manual out http://www.php.net/manual/en/stats.installation.php. It is definitely not a default part of PHP and has to be installed if you wish to use it

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys. I thought it was part of PHP. I will take a look at the manual and try to install PECL. Thanks!

Comment: @RiggsFolly you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

As the comments said, the PECL package is not installed in your system, look [here](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php) to install.

But, if you can't install, or you don't want to install it, you can use this function

```
function std_deviation($arr){
    $arr_size=count($arr);
    $mu=array_sum($arr)/$arr_size;
    $ans=0;
    foreach($arr as $elem){
        $ans+=pow(($elem-$mu),2);
    }
    return sqrt($ans/$arr_size);
}
```

That follows the [standard deviation formula](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation-formulas.html).